# Double Integrals on continuous functions

Tags: calculus

Let $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a continuous function. Show that
$$\int_{y=0}^a\int_{x=0}^y f(x)dxdy=\int_{x=0}^a(a-x)f(x)dx.$$

Answer (score 0):

The region of integration $0\leq x\leq y$, $0\leq y\leq a$ on the left is the same as the region $x\leq y\leq a$, $0\leq x\leq a$. You can see that they represent the same triangular region on the plane. So the left double integral becomes $$\int_{x=0}^a\int_{y=x}^af(x)dydx$$ which evaluates to the right side integral.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the order of integration:

$I=\int\limits_0^a f(x)dx\int\limits_x^ady=\int\limits_0^a(a-x)f(x)dx. $

Comment: You should specify $\int_0^a \left( f(x)dx \int_x^a dy \right)$, as you are not multiplying two independent integrals together.

Comment: Check the question again.

Comment: I thought this was a common convention that $\int\limits_0^a f(x)dx\int\limits_x^ag(y)dy$ is the same as $\int\limits_0^a \left(\int\limits_x^ag(y)dy\right)f(x)dx$ that allows you not to use parentheses

Comment: Maths Geek, Read the post of PJK. My post was exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier in this case to just integrate by parts:
$$ \int_{y=0}^a \int_{x=0}^y f(x) \, dx \, dy = \left[-(a-y)\int_{x=0}^y f(x) \, dx \right]_0^{a}+ \int_{y=0}^a (a-y) f(y) \, dy $$
It's a slightly funny antiderivative of $1$ I've chosen, but this way, the boundary terms vanish, and the result follows.